# Можно ли стилизовать пусть маршрута в Google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

Можно ли стилизовать пусть маршрута в Google maps, чтобы дорогу от точки до точки можно было покрасить в произвольный цвет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/google-maps-javascript-api) посмотрите

```
var polylineOptions={};
polylineOptions.strokeColor="#438391";
polylineOptions.strokeOpacity=.6;
polylineOptions.strokeWeight=4;

 //now assign to map render options
mapRendererOptions.polylineOptions=polylineOptions;

//now set renderer
directionsDisplay.setOptions(
new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(mapRendererOptions));
```

Также по Вашему вопросу на [англоязычном](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311498/change-the-color-of-the-polyline-in-directionsrenderer) stackoverflow